# Where are my emails stored on CentOS 5.6

Tags: centos, email, virtual-machine, sendmail

I have a CentOS 5.6 VM installation and currently have a handful of emails that I would like to get access to.

When I run `mail` as root, I get:

```
[root@dev mail]# mail
Mail version 8.1 6/6/93.  Type ? for help.
"/var/spool/mail/root": 11 messages 11 unread
>U  1 logwatch@www.crmpicco.d  Mon Feb 17 10:06  44/1625  "Logwatch for dev.localdomain (Linux)"
```

Where is that file stored? I would like to send it on to someone for review.

I can't see it in `/var/spool/mail/`.

Answer (score 7):

The `/var/spool/mail/` is the folder that mail is saved as a file as `/var/spool/mail/$USER`.

- when you call `mail` it will by default read that file.
- all read mails will be stored in `mbox` file and you can access them using `mail -f ~/mbox`.

Comment: In @crmpicco 's example root's unread and/or unhandled mail is stored in `/var/spool/mail/root` where `root` is a file.

Answer (score 0):

But it should, indeed, be in there; try an "ls -al /var/spool/mail/root".  That should show it to you.  Note, however, that you will only have that one mail file; "mbox"-formatted mail (which is what's generally stored in /var/spool/mail/) compiles each folder into one aggregate ASCII file that the client then parses.  This is notably different from the way that maildir works, where each e-mail is a different on-disk file, with folders being implemented by way of separate directories.